# unable to add functionality of password reset in my app. Using parse.com

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, reset, forgot-password

I used parse.com as back end service in my android app. Now i want to add password reset feature in my application but it isn't working. When i perform click it doesn't give me error and neither it is showing me success message.I followed parse.com's docs. Help me

Here is my code.

```
 public class ResetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView resetTv;
EditText resetEt;
Button resetButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

    resetTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_reset);
    resetEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etresetemail);
    resetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String email = resetEt.toString();

            try{
                ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(email, new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            resetTv.setText("An Email has been send to your email account! Follow the procedure");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! Try later" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha Silly mistake. I figured it out.

```
String email=resetEt.getText().toString();
```

It is working now :)